# How can I recognize slightly modified images?

Tags: image-processing, hash, fuzzy-comparison

I have a very large database of jpeg images, about 2 million.  I would like to do a fuzzy search for duplicates among those images.  Duplicate images are two images that have many (around half) of their pixels with identical values and the rest are off by about +/- 3 in their R/G/B values.  The images are identical to the naked eye.  It's the kind of difference you'd get from re-compressing a jpeg.

I already have a foolproof way to detect if two images are identical: I sum the delta-brightness over all the pixels and compare to a threshold.  This method has proven 100% accurate but doing 1 photo against 2 million is incredibly slow (hours per photo).

I would like to fingerprint the images in a way that I could just compare the fingerprints in a hash table.  Even if I can reliably whittle down the number of images that I need to compare to just 100, I would be in great shape to compare 1 to 100.  What would be a good algorithm for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at O. Chum, J. Philbin, and A. Zisserman, [Near duplicate image detection: min-hash and tf-idf weighting](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/papers/chum08a.pdf), in Proceedings of the British Machine Vision Conference, 2008. They solve the problem you have and demonstrate the results for 146k images. However, I have no first-hand experience with their approach.

Comment: Always nice to see peer-reviewed publications on SO.  +1

Comment: I used min-Hash with fantastic results.  In short: 24 hours to index 1million photos.  20images classified per second.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Here is the code: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spt/2008/06/10/set-similarity-and-min-hash/

Comment: For anyone else reading the paper and wondering what a Visual Word is (it is assumed you know)... https://towardsdatascience.com/bag-of-visual-words-in-a-nutshell-9ceea97ce0fb

Answer (score 3):

Naive idea: create a small thumbnail (50x50 pixels) to find "probably identical" images, then increase thumbnail size to discard more images.

Comment: I don't follow.  I tried comparing small images, 25x25, and they, too, have differences invisible to the naked eye.

Comment: @Eyal - If at 25x25 two images look identical, they may still be different, but if they look different, they *are* different. You already have an algorithm to detect identical images  but it's slow. So, my suggestion is to first create a subset of your images which look the same at 25x25 and discard the rest of the images. Then create a 50x50 image of this subset and compare again, more images will be discarded. Then again at 100x100, etc. The idea is at each iteration you'll have a more cpu/disk intensive process for each image, but with fewer images(sorry if I didn't understand your problem)

Comment: You need to limit the color space. RGB images have 2 ^ (3 * 8) == 16777216 colors. Downscaled images will surely differ in colors subtly and produce different hashes. Try to limit the color space to say 2 ^ (3 * 2) == 64 colors. However this also is not ideal because a small change in a picture might push a pixel into a different downscaled color. Perhaps weight the average color changes instead and if they don't exceed a threshold, report a match. Perhaps a YUV color model variant like YUV420 is better suited to the way human eye perceives differences.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the idea of minHash...

My idea is to make 100 look-up tables using all the images currently in the database.  The look-up tables are mapping from the brightness of a particular pixel to a list of images that have that same brightness in that same pixel.  To search for an image just input it into the hash tables, get 100 lists, and score a point for each image when it shows up in a list.  Each image will have a score from 0 to 100.  The image with the most points wins.

There are many issues with how to do this within reasonable memory constraints and how to do it quickly.  Proper data structures are needed for storage on disk.  Tweaking of the hashing value, number of tables, etc, is possible, too.  If more information is needed, I can expand on this.

My results have been very good.  I'm able to index one million images in about 24 hours on one computer and I can lookup 20 images per second.  Accuracy is astounding as far as I can tell.

Comment: I would to see you writting a blog article about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this problem can be solved by hashing.  Here's the difficulty: suppose you have a red pixel, and you want 3 and 5 to hash to the same value.  Well, then you also want 5 and 7 to hash to the same value, and 7 and 9, and so on... you can construct a chain that says you want all pixels to hash to the same value.

Here's what I would try instead:

1. Build a huge B-tree, with 32-way fanout at each node, containing all of the images.
2. All images in the tree are the same size, or they're not duplicates.
3. Give each colored pixel a unique number starting at zero.  Upper left might be numbered 0, 1, 2 for the R, G, B components, or you might be better off with a random permutation, because you're going to compare images in order of that numbering.
4. An internal node at depth n discriminates 32 ways on the value of the pixel n divided by 8 (this gets out some of the noise in nearby pixels.
5. A leaf node contains some small number of images, let's say 10 to 100.  Or maybe the number of images is an increasing function of depth, so that if you have 500 duplicates of one image, after a certain depth you stop trying to distinguish them.

One all two million nodes are inserted in the tree, two images are duplicate only if they're at the same node.  Right?  Wrong!  If the pixel value in two images are 127 and 128, one goes into outedge 15 and the other goes into outedge 16.  So actually when you discriminate on a pixel, you may insert that image into one *or two* children:

- For brightness `B`, insert at `B/8`, `(B-3)/8`, and `(B+3)/8`.  Sometimes all 3 will be equal, and always 2 of 3 will be equal.  But with probability 3/8, you double the number of outedges on which the image appears.  Depending on how deep things go you could have lots of extra nodes.

Someone else will have to do the math and see if you have to divide by something larger than 8 to keep images from being duplicated too much.  The good news is that even if the true fanout is only around 4 instead of 32, you only need a tree of depth 10.  Four duplications in 10 takes you up to 32 million images at the leaves.  I hope you have plenty of RAM at your disposal!  If not, you can put the tree in the filesystem.

Let me know how this goes!

Comment: What your reasoning shows is that for any similarity-based hash function, there must be _some_ similar images that have different hashes.  The hope is that most similar images do not.

Also, an appropriate hash function could give you an efficient way to compute a _distance_ between two images, such that similar images have smaller distances than dissimilar images.

Answer (score 1):

Also good about hash from thumbnails: scaled duplicates are recognized (with little modification)